# Push multiple nupkg files to Github Packages using powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, github-actions, github-package-registry

We are consolidating on Github, and I am looking into how to get one of our C# projects to build using Github Actions, and push the generated nuget packages to Github Packages.  My test project generates about 15 packages.

It appears that the "dotnet nuget push" command only supports pushing one file at a time so I am trying to write a powershell script that does roughly the same as this shell command

```
find . -name '*.nupkg' -exec '/usr/bin/echo' 'dotnet nuget push "{}" --source github' ';' | sh -v -
```

In other words, generate a "dotnet nuget push "..." --source github" command for each nupkg file found.

So far I've found the powershell command `Get-Childitem -Path . -Recurse -Include *.nupkg` which gets the files as far as I can see, but where I need the "execute command on *this* file" bit.  I'd also like to have the command executed echoed too before execution similar to what the "-v" flag does.

Also, if there is a simpler way to do this (others must have had this problem before and solved it more elegantly) I'd consider that instead.

Thanks.

How

Answer (score 4):

To push to nuget.org, you should be able to use the following command:

```
dotnet nuget push "**/*.nupkg" --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TO_NUGET_ORG }} --skip-duplicate
```

To push to your github.com feed, you should be able to use the following command, which you should find works consistently (also for bigger nuget packages, eg. multi-target packages):

```
nuget.exe push "**/*.nupkg" -NoSymbols -SkipDuplicate
```

In case you're using GitHub Actions,

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
        # Authenticates packages to push to GPR
        source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: '%NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN%'
    
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: msbuild /t:Restore
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    
    - name: Build
      run: |
        msbuild /t:Pack /p:Configuration=Debug Library/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj
        dotnet pack Library\MintPlayer.MVVM.BaseModel\MintPlayer.MVVM.BaseModel.csproj --configuration=Release
    
    - name: PushNuget
      run: dotnet nuget push "**/*.nupkg" --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TO_NUGET_ORG }} --skip-duplicate
    
    - name: PushGithub
      run: nuget.exe push "**/*.nupkg" -NoSymbols -SkipDuplicate
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

At the moment github.com doesn't have a symbol server, hence the use of the `-NoSymbols` flag.

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking at Github Packages, not nuget.org.  The SkipDuplicate is interesting -I would like to for now to have what Maven calls SNAPSHOT's, in other words non-permanent packages which _can_ be overwritten with never versions.  Do you know how I should approach that?

Comment: Oh, and this project I am looking at right now, generates about 10 nupkg files.  Can you confirm that the "dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg" command works with multiple files for you?

Comment: Oh it seems I did try, and I can tell it works. However the older versions of `setup-dotnet` and `setup-msbuild` are deprecated. Posted a new version of my action

Comment: And sadly I don't have any experience with MVN packages. Java is not my Cup<T>. Perhaps someone else who can elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic solution here would be to pipe the resulting file info objects to `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter *.nupkg |ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "About to push a package named '$($_.Name)'..." 
  dotnet nuget push $_.FullName --source github
}
```

Inside the `ForEach-Object` block, `$_` refers to the individual currently item being processed/iterated over.

Note that most PowerShell cmdlets return *complex objects* (as opposed to string-based output) - hence the `$_.FullName` expression - the `FullName` property contains the rooted path to the file in question (ie. `C:\path\to\package.nupkg`)

Comment: Thanks.  Does this syntax support printing multiple lines?  I'd like to print out the file name found (surrounded by asterisks if possible) before actually executing the command.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sure, you can add whatever statements you like in the script block, updated the example

Comment: You can actually push all nuget packages present in a folder in a single command: `dotnet nuget push "**/*.nupkg"`